# Adjust the selicho “מַשְׂאַת כַּפַּי" when the kehillo is not fasting on Yom Kippur Koton?

Tags: fast-days, selichot, contradiction, yom-kippur-katan

Related: [Who observes Yom Kippur Katan, and how?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55469/who-observes-yom-kippur-katan-and-how)

In the mincha service of Yom Kippur Koton, the selicho “מַשְׂאַת כַּפַּי” is said:

> 1 *חזן* מַשְׂאַת כַּפַּי מִנְחַת עֶרֶב רְצֵה נָא בְכֹשֶׁר, תִּכּוֹן
>   תְּפִלָּתִי קְטוֹרֶת לְפָנֶיךָ בְּתֹם וּבְיֹשֶׁר, בְּקָרְאִי עֲנֵנִי
>   צוּרִי הַיּוֹם יִפְנֶה:
>
> *קהל* - כַּאֲשֶׁר יָבִיאוּ בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל אֶת הַמִּנְחָה:
>
> 2 *חזן* - רֵיחַ נִיחוֹחַ אִמְרֵי פִי לְפָנֶיךָ צוּר עוֹלָמִים,
>   חֶלְבִּי וְדָמִי הַנִּמְעַט בְּצוֹמִי תְּמוּר חֲלָבִים וְדָמִים,
>   קַבֵּל הֶגְיוֹן לִבִּי אֲשֶׁר עָרַכְתִּי הַיּוֹם ( נ"א זֶה כַּמָה
>   יָמִים) בַּנְעִימִים:
>
> *קהל* - כְּחַטָּאת כָּאָשָׁם וְכַמִּנְחָה:

In the second stanza, the words  חֶלְבִּי וְדָמִי הַנִּמְעַט בְּצוֹמִי (= my fat and my blood which are reduced through my fast) are said.

My limited experience of  Yom Kippur Koton has been with kehillos that do not fast, but nevertheless say this stanza. That seems to me to be less than honest.

Does anyone know of a minhag to change this stanza when not fasting?

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95408/759

Comment: Notably, this slicha was originally a central part of Yom Kippur Mincha when surely everyone was really fasting. Reciting it on Yom Kippur Katan is meant to invoke the real Yom Kippur (Gadol?) but nowadays the allusion is lost on most.